# Unzip internal ZIP file to path

Tags: c#, .net, zip, compression

I have a application that I want to copy directories within a internal ZIP to a path.

Did some searching and found this: [Decompress byte array to string via BinaryReader yields empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013771/decompress-byte-array-to-string-via-binaryreader-yields-empty-string). However, the result is simply bytes. I haven't a clue about how to translate this back into folders that can then be moved to a path. (Working with just bytes is confusing to me)

Doing some more searching on here pointed me to the .NET 4.5 feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

There's one complication, I don't have a zip path, rather a **array of bytes** from the zip kept internally inside my application. Keeping this in mind, how would I go about using this `ZipFile` feature but instead with a array of bytes as a input?

Some other things I've looked at:

- [Compress a single file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042141/compress-a-single-file-using-c-sharp)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- [How to extract zip file contents into a folder in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773371/how-to-extract-zip-file-contents-into-a-folder-in-net-4-5)

Note, for this particular application, I'd like to **refrain from using external DLL's**. A portable CLI executable is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: `ZipArchive` works on streams, so wrap your bytes in a `MemoryStream` and decompress from that. Your question is too broad, so there's no point in trying to answer it. You should _try something_ and post a question when you have something _specific_ to ask.

Comment: I just did some looking at MSDN's page on `MemoryStream`. I don't know how or what you mean by "wrap your bytes". Can I have a example?

Comment: You might consider acquainting yourself with the search tools available on the Internet, and even on this very web site. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+ziparchive+memorystream

Answer (score 0):

In order to satisfy both the need that I have only bytes and unzip the bytes (without using `MemoryBuffer` as that still makes no sense to me), I ended up creating a temporary folder, creating a empty file in that folder, filling it with the bytes of the zipped file then using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory()` to extract it to the final destination.
It may not be the most efficient, but it works quite well.