# Not able to Decompress the byte array of new secure QR code of Aadhar

Tags: c#, compression, qr-code, gzipstream, binarystream

I am trying to decompress the byte array using GZipStream but getting error of "Found invalid data while decoding."

// getting aadhaar sample qr code data from
// https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          string source = "6979414848205548481619299442879901900893978332594614407044767717485407280104077714658698163325401659212830920734233047578454701810567032015270223682917915825234703754712504887921309181789607809168884583848396456653007022479356336240198130363930881632367124738541517499494458139647378808680614169273221404741476596583953169248831376224396335169577064812987140578144885819479190173537644970232125142253963784979138011318798385442436099901621998283624816070080504830712594525760596934341576755626791590403636878139861665599383319429228364434183913197958738697001410493839281298692342829951566712530309758759364649701153639921979798429707566199261950037418171329283207372048014948669160666776198414040633384677104717697507521717586776709084200364956178863636105988867260929887577092955570407803783021397897341999914616790441029837229129746669225095633201097644321593502503404440714110515167034889128258965583435965030225845348564582051521348800742574442877087774194668983516629631073341202705453382780613775427336949283388084891654484225446940941660942440637784744293259916479841407088189462964489670231866481904237338494872813098890875845640034370370387108798950180220865436012752487216677041817312930119747601017807577565413977545693375480131324240696099879479436722576566447939593195590684591261809038023122178172006150499569185218838749337238281597037288924464009997530938336798176023597292328320965086990184531426188862965408313308973495924965144113396593829090645266653313774582036138982013368561474719154447134894466611560589758251829063226370300282175823479569847261439348404558251402273730865053482214589180028302043821438357583302818374143973997002745047526405755760407045006694423501337081780299815080324840337828812644300041900356816429114261098230198976752026002079876882796597235615015594486182057781476152918170746403157005216896239428521706033466061587608065036133153074432195952131368564234168005447770190345777024917629879639171161719929852078265309160759260989590618158889891835294735614366674503961584445497685736312628248483551986529867423016255476553691922054241686230968975229511700928171281549902682365302333677412951788839806869796040512235899311734337858684531156721416280114473368826463098485252394260075790386415875290922570568686439586036262465414002334117870088922801660529414759784318799843806130096998190881240404138869293309782335305296720666220243304175086358278211355789957998014801209332293458940463859106591986434520433810583569309224929264228263841477378949329312443958215939294432669464260216534074560882723006838459792812340253078330291135526952675203790833430237852831740601433198364243363569730205351077393441691141240055900819091229931605146865520183001810239708464322588389956036291760175558843819105418234580239610174323636606095262722940143706063698846499673285377621180570537788160304936809915237889489342387891057012783726694920184573202789672963922380028271124448024265644396686341508447830351380242127542393849410283830409594988503246799544444687606954881510597515686410993828907588979699141180160893062603338104857903239845856783130275935413569275439908789983311663211937449259444259898972766208";
          BigInteger.TryParse(source, out BigInteger numBig);
          byte[] bytes = numBig.ToByteArray();
          string isoBytes2 = Decompress(bytes);
       }

static string Decompress(byte[] gzBuffer)
      {
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
              int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
              ms.Write(gzBuffer, 0, gzBuffer.Length);

              byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];

              ms.Position = 0;
              int length;
              using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
              {
                  length = zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
              }

              var data = new byte[length];
              Array.Copy(buffer, data, length);
              return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

          }
      }
```

Comment: your decompression function looks incorrect to me where you define length of decompressed array. Please try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7015117/11843739

Comment: @fenixil, i have used your suggested function but no luck. Getting same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64341259/8362967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, we need to do reverse byte array after coverting byte array from biginteger and before decompression the byte array. 
In Java, it not needed.